# Do the Centurions ever come back to Earth?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, robots, cylon

In regard to the newer Battlestar Gallactica series,

> In the last episode, the humans and the "nice" cylons find Earth and decide to
>  start anew. They let the Centurions (toasters) go and give them the base ship.
>  However, is it known if they ever come back and the cycle begins all over again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure the the Centurions never return to Earth.

The story cycle pretty much demands that humans reinvent 
the cylons over and over again so we can experience the
hubris that all modern scifi seems to think we need.

Comment: If they had, they'd probably be running the place now.  Since they still had all the high tech and the humans and human form cylons had given it all up.